# Get bogus value when execute break point in a variable

Tags: swift, xcode, breakpoints

[image: Code]

I got a bogus value of `finalScore`, what happened?

I want to know why `finalScore` is `4339953456` rather than a correct number `520`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your breakpoint is *on* the `finalScore =` line, it means that the program is stopped *before* this value has been computed.

It should show no value instead of a bogus value, probably, but this is not something that you have to worry about: set your breakpoint one line later and your `finalScore` will have a proper value.