# Swift Double value in Struct shifting

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm writing an iOS app on XCode 8.1 and Swift 3.0 and I've encountered a very strange behaviour:

I've defined a struct named Point:

```
struct Point {
    let latitud: Double, longitude: Double, id: Int
}
```

And I've defined a function which returns a Point array from a XML document (simplified version):

```
  func getPointsFromXML(_ document: AEXMLDocument) -> [Point] {
        var ret: [Point] = []
        do {
            if let pointsAux = document.root[pointsNode][pointNode].all {
                for pointAux in pointsAux {
                    let auxPoint = Point(latitud: <lat>, longitude: <lon>, id: <id>
                    ret.append(auxPoint)
                }
            } else {
                throw TrailError.trailPointsNotFound
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return ret
    }
```

The strange part comes here. If I inspect `auxPoint` it contains correctly gathered values:

[image: enter ## Heading ##image description here]

Then, if I inspect the `ret` array, onto which I've appended `auxPoint`, the values change completely:

[image]

It's not a data representation issue, as the binary value of the numbers is also different.

Comment: On which line do you set your breakpoint when you get these values? I'm asking because your issue looks a bit like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816724/get-bogus-value-when-using-break-point-before-a-variable-in-swift), could be the same problem.

Comment: Right after I've set the value for `auxPoint`, and right after I've added it to the `ret` array (lines 7 and 8, respectively)

Comment: It didn't solve the issue. The values are still wrong even after initialization.

Comment: What do you get for `p ret` in the debugger console? Then debugger variables view is sometimes just wrong. You could also add `print(ret)` to your code to double-check the issue.

Comment: In your second screenshot `ret` looks like an Optional array, this is weird...

Comment: When printing them they where actually right, so weird...

Comment: Are you sure you're not attempting to inspect the `ret` array prior to it getting a first member? Since you try to access the `[0]`th index (hence the optionality), if it has no member there, then the values to inspect of that non-existant `Point` member will be jibberish.

Comment: I've checked the final value of `ret`, after the method finishes, and it has the wrong values. Although it prints them just fine. Very weird.