# Unable to read data while making request

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurl, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

here i am getting strange issue like i can able to make request into simulator but in real device gave error like "unable to read data" also attached screen shot[image]

My Code :

```
    let urlPath: String = url_to_request
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
```

Comment: You can ignore that message, unless the method is not performing what you wish. Also, I tried on playground everything works properly.

Comment: in the end im not getting any response but same thing working with my simulator.

Comment: 1- Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/37812485/2227743, it *will* help. 2- Read http://stackoverflow.com/a/37816856/2227743, it *might* help.